# How to make pane of Highchart Solidgauge rounded

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

Here you guys can see I have rounded edge on my arcs but for pane it is flat.
Is there any way I can get rounded pane also.
I am using Highcharts v9.1.2
I've tried stroke-linejoin : "round" but that also didn't worked.

[image]

Let me know if you guys need any code reference.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you had in mind [stroke-linecap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap)

Comment: Yup That's also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stroke-linecap` solution seems to work correctly. Try the following example:

**Example config:**

```
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  chart: {
    type: 'solidgauge',
    events: {
      load() {
        this.pane[0].group.element.getElementsByTagName('path')[0].setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linejoin', 'round');
      }
    }
  },
  pane: {
    size: '100%',
    startAngle: 0,
    endAngle: 300,
    background: {
      borderWidth: 30,
      shape: 'arc',
      outerRadius: '90%',
      innerRadius: '90%'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    solidgauge: {
      innerRadius: '80%',
      radius: '100%',
      linecap: "round",
      rounded: true
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    tickPositions: []
  },
  series: [{
    data: [70],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/usbha9c1/

Comment: I was missing borderWidth. Thanks